# Modify dates in POSIXct format in R using lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have five dates in the following format:

```
five_dates <- c("2015-04-13 22:56:01 UTC", "2015-04-13 23:00:29 UTC", "2014-04-13 23:01:22 UTC", "2013-04-13 23:01:39 UTC", "2013-04-13 23:01:43 UTC")
```

Using the `lubridate` package, I processed them by doing the following:

```
five_dates <- lubridate::ymd_hms(five_dates)
str(five_dates)
[1] POSIXct[1:5], format: "2015-04-13 22:56:01" "2015-04-13 23:00:29" "2014-04-13 23:01:22" "2013-04-13 23:01:39" "2013-04-13 23:01:43"
```

I want to add one year to the dates in 2013:

```
five_dates <- ifelse(lubridate::year(five_dates) < 2014, five_dates + years(1), five_dates)
```

But doing so leads to this output:

```
five_dates
[1] 1428965761 1428966029 1397430082 1397430099 1397430103
```

How can I add one year to dates in 2013 so the output is also a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `ifelse()`.  It strips attributes.

But since you are using the *lubridate* package anyway, why not use its `year<-` replacement function to replace the year with a different one?  With it we can avoid `ifelse()` all together.

```
yr <- 2013
year(five_dates[year(five_dates) == yr]) <- yr + 1
five_dates
# [1] "2015-04-13 22:56:01 UTC" "2015-04-13 23:00:29 UTC"
# [3] "2014-04-13 23:01:22 UTC" "2014-04-13 23:01:39 UTC"
# [5] "2014-04-13 23:01:43 UTC"
```

Or using your code, you could grab the class before the `ifelse()` call, then assign it back.

```
cl <- class(five_dates)
five_dates <- ifelse(...)
class(five_dates) <- cl
```

Examples are shown in `help(ifelse)`.  But I think `year<-` will help you out more here since you are already using the *lubridate* package.

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because I think I prefer to stay in `lubridate` land.

Comment: Good answer. @JoshuaRosenberg the 2nd option in my answer is also in *lubridate-land* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`ifelse` removes the date-formatting. You need to transform it back:

```
five_dates <- as.POSIXct(five_dates, origin="1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
```

which gives:

```
> five_dates
[1] "2015-04-13 22:56:01 UTC" "2015-04-13 23:00:29 UTC"
[3] "2014-04-13 23:01:22 UTC" "2014-04-13 23:01:39 UTC"
[5] "2014-04-13 23:01:43 UTC"
```

An alternative for the `ifelse` operation which achieves the same:

```
five_dates <- five_dates + years(as.integer(year(five_dates) < 2014))
```

gives:

```
> five_dates
[1] "2015-04-13 22:56:01 UTC" "2015-04-13 23:00:29 UTC"
[3] "2014-04-13 23:01:22 UTC" "2014-04-13 23:01:39 UTC"
[5] "2014-04-13 23:01:43 UTC"
```